# Woocommece - how to change the layout of shortcode template

Tags: woocommerce

I am using this shortcode to show all products of a specific product category on custom a template.

```
[products limit="12" columns="3"]
```

Now, as I am developing a new theme so the output of this shortcode is breaking the design.

I want to know where or which file I should take or edit to change the layout I want?

Check this image:

[image]

Here you can see the rectangle box **div's** is coming from the content-product.php page but I want to add/change few div before that **div's**

Like where the `<div class="row">` and `<div class="woocommerce columns-3 ">` is coming? I want to change it.